# Can't start activity from fragment, getting IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I try to start an activity from my fragment but get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as
>   non-null is null: method
>   kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter
>   bundle

I use java and don't know why I get kotlin error

this is my fragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentLoginBinding binding;
private AuthSharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    sharedViewModel = ((LoginActivity) getActivity()).viewModel;
    binding.setViewmodel(sharedViewModel);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

    onClickListener();

    return binding.getRoot();
}

private void onClickListener() {

    binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    sharedViewModel.getIsFetchSmsSuccessful().removeObservers(this);
   }

}
```

code get error on fragment but work on activity.

any body can help??

Comment: at what point do you get the error? when you click on the button in the fragment? or when you open this fragment?

Comment: @droidbaza bouth of them

Comment: your log Error show that bundle parameter is null.this means that you are probably incorrectly requesting / using bundle. for example you dont include check(if bundle!=null).hard to say without seeing your code

Comment: 1st.  add check for null in yor destroyView (if (sharedViewModel!=null) {sharedViewModel.getIsFetchSmsSuccessful().removeObservers(this)};2d replace this line  "sharedViewModel = ((LoginActivity) getActivity()).viewModel;" - (instead getActivity - activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my god dammit solution. the problem is I use KeyboardVisibilityEvent library to control hide and visibility keyboard.

I use this code to control:

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(getActivity(), this::updateKeyboardStatusText);
```

but I must pass the activity in method to handle life cycle

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(getActivity(), getActivity(), this::updateKeyboardStatusText);
```

hope help someone.
thanks everyone

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. Next time please post more code and also the complete error message including the line number at which the exception get's thrown .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code instead "getActivity" in your fragment:

```
private AppCompatActivity activity;

 @Override
  public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
      super.onAttach(context);
      if (context instanceof AppCompatActivity) {
        activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
    }
  }
```

then in your clickListener

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
 activity.startActivity(intent);
 activity.finish();
```

Comment: Please also explain *why* this is a better solution?

Comment: @RobAu thanks but not working, still get the same error

Comment: @RobAu If getActivity () returns null, then the fragment is either disconnected from the activity or not yet attached. (A pending commit transaction occurs)

Comment: @droidbaza getActivity() doesn't return null. it has value, I use the activity in another parts of this fragment, I don't think the problem is activity

Comment: i know.i update comment higher. it’s just that you brought a snippet of code with getActivity

Comment: , believing that the problem is in it. therefore, we began to look for the right solution for the use of getActivity. but the problem is different. problem in bundle

Answer (score 0):

Try without the second `getActivity()`. The method `startActivity()` exist in the Fragment class too.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Edit:
You call the onClickListener at a time when the activity might not be ready.
[More about the fragment lifecycle.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#lifecycle)
Try this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    onClickListener();
}
```

Or in `@Override public void onViewCreated`

Comment: Did you try new Intent(this, NewActivity.class); too? Did you get the same error?

Comment: this code in activity works fine but when try to use in fragment with getActivity() get error.

Comment: I just tried this code and it's working in Fragments too. Maybe you can post more of your code so we know when exactly this is being called.

Comment: this is the whole fragment class

Comment: Try calling onClickListener() at a different time in the fragment lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to open activity from fragment you need to use
>   FragmentActivity

so simply do like this

```
   binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener{
        activity?.let{
            it.startActivity(Intent (it, MainActivity::class.java))
            it.finish()
        }
    }
```

> or

```
 binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener{
        requireActivity().startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(),MainActivity::class.java))
        requireActivity().finish()
    }
```

> both `activity?.let{}`  and `requireActivity()` are FragmentActivity

One thing i notice from your error message is

> Parameter specified as non-null is null: method
>   kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter
>   bundle

so I would add @Nullable at Bundle savedInstanceState

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    sharedViewModel = ((LoginActivity) getActivity()).viewModel;
    binding.setViewmodel(sharedViewModel);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

    onClickListener();

    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

one more thing
you need to switch your code like this

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    sharedViewModel.getIsFetchSmsSuccessful().removeObservers(this);
    super.onDestroyView();

}
```

> because you want to removeObservers before it destroy view

This is what it should look like in kotlin

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
    private var binding: FragmentLoginBinding? = null
    private var sharedViewModel: AuthSharedViewModel? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
        sharedViewModel = (activity as LoginActivity).viewModel
        binding.setViewmodel(sharedViewModel)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)       
        return binding.getRoot()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        onClickListener()
    }


    private fun onClickListener() {
        binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener{
            activity?.startActivity(Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java))
            activity?.finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        sharedViewModel.getIsFetchSmsSuccessful().removeObservers(this)
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}
```

> this is Java

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentLoginBinding binding;
    private AuthSharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        sharedViewModel = ((LoginActivity) getActivity()).viewModel;
        binding.setViewmodel(sharedViewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onClickListener();
    }

    private void onClickListener() {
        binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        sharedViewModel.getIsFetchSmsSuccessful().removeObservers(this);
        super.onDestroyView();

    }

}
```

Comment: @AbbasTorabi  I edited my code please check it again

Comment: Moving the onClickListerner() from onCreateView to onViewCreated is exactly what i wrote 2hours ago.

Comment: @einUserName yes i see your post i just rearrange it,  but i don't think it's the main problem,  the problem should be that parameter bundle is Null  that is why he should add `@Nullable` Bundle savedInstanceState first. at onCreateView() i mean